Kafka & Http (Graphql, Rest) in one jar
We have an Uber spring-boot jar containing Kafka & http processing. We are noticing that
if the HTTP requests (graphql, rest) are high the kafka consumer thread is starving, meaning events are read/processed slowly.
Is it architecturally incorrect to combine two high-processing processes under one application? Should we split http from kafka ?
Any suggestions?
Thanks
